# How do i take out specific data from my list and store in a individual variable

Tags: python, list, variables

I have a list that look like this

```
myList = [2,4,6,8]
```

I want to take out the specific element from the list and store it in another variable

```
a = myList[3]

print (a)
```

By right the answer should give me 6 but i do not understand why it keep giving me error.

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Indices start at zero, so `a = myList[2]` equals to `6` in your example.

Comment: It gives you an error or gives you 8, lists are zero-indexed so the first element is at index 0, and 6 is at index 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
a = myList[2]
```

List elements are assigned indexes [0,1,2,....]